# Execute bash script that will continue though Apache restarts

Tags: bash, apache

I need to have a bash script triggered and run, but part of the script requires Apache to restart. This obviously kills the script from continuing. I can't move the restarts in the script to the end

I have tried to run the bash scrip though a php script using shell_exec() in a GNU screen session to keep it going but that doesn't work. as soon as Apache goes down the script stops.
There has to be a way to do this but I'm not seeing it.

How I can accomplish this?

Comment: Can you just set a wait time in your script before continuing to execute the script

Comment: No, it seems like its killing the script and even with a sleep time of 10 to allow Apache to come back up it doesn't continue with the script

It's really frustrating. if I run the trigger script manually though a ssh connection it works but wont when triggered by a php or cgi script on the webserver

Comment: Don't execute via php, apache is the application which parses php

Comment: I tried to get around that by using GNU screen. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Does `nohup` do the job?

> nohup is a POSIX command which means "no hang up". Its purpose is to execute a command such that it ignores the HUP (hangup) signal and therefore does not stop when the user logs out.
> Output that would normally go to the terminal goes to a file called nohup.out, if it has not already been redirected.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup

Comment: No dice, script still dies when Apache is restarted